# Choosing option to close own answered question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, accepted-answer, close-reasons, help-center

I want to close my question, as it is answered, because I think my question is solved with given answer so which options must I choose from the below to close a question?
Which option is suitable?

- **duplicate of...**
  This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- **off-topic because…**
  (too old to migrate) This question does not appear to be about Ubuntu within the scope defined in the help center.
- **unclear what you're asking** 
  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
- **too broad**
  Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
- **primarily opinion-based**
  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Can you fix that first sentence?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've to change question's aspect. Thanks

Comment: Please don’t completely change your question, especially once you have an (accepted) answer.

Comment: Closed is wrong term. The correct term is "having accepted answer". "Closed" means "does not accept any new answer".

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Yes that I want, I won't getting more and more answer as I've already accepted one which solved my problem.

Comment: That's not your choice to make. The focus of Stack Exchange is content. If someone can give a new answer to your question, it might help others. You don't get to decide to block this, even if the question is yours. Most you can do it mark existing answer as accepted, then people who come to post answer will notice there's already accepted answer so will think twice before posting a new answer,  but that's it.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard. So why some questions are closed even if they are good?

Comment: What you define "good" might not really be good for the site. Questions are closed for various reasons, you listed it here yourself. Yet again, single person can't decide what's good and what's bad for a site, that's something the community as whole is doing, more likely 5 users with high reputation. (Or one moderator, who is trusted to do those things.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Ok, Thank you so much for your invaluable time to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's none of the above.

Questions are only closed when they are unsuitable for receiving answers.  Having received an answer is not a reason for not receiving more answers.

Instead of closing your question you should upvote any answers that helped you and/or accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer, as explained in [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) faq.